# Next button in keyboard not coming while filing HTML5 form in Android

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a simple HTML5 form, opened in Android webview.
But while filing the input textboxes, the keyboard is coming but, the next button ( ->| ) 
is not coming.

What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got few points, that prevent the 'Next' button to come

- Form having
- If the page is in 'multiple pages in Single page'
- having blank `<script> or <style>`